# 3 Levels Linear Models in R with random slopes and intercepts with hierarchy level variables

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to write a 3 level multilevel linear model in `R`, using `lme4`.

I've decided to use the data from this question as a guide: [Crossed vs nested random effects: how do they differ and how are they specified correctly in lme4?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified)

```
library("lme4")
dt <-read.table("http://bayes.acs.unt.edu:8083/BayesContent/class/Jon/R_SC/Module9/lmm.data.txt",
                 header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE) 

> head(dt)
  id    extro     open    agree    social class school
1  1 63.69356 43.43306 38.02668  75.05811     d     IV
2  2 69.48244 46.86979 31.48957  98.12560     a     VI
3  3 79.74006 32.27013 40.20866 116.33897     d     VI
4  4 62.96674 44.40790 30.50866  90.46888     c     IV
5  5 64.24582 36.86337 37.43949  98.51873     d     IV
6  6 50.97107 46.25627 38.83196  75.21992     d      I
```

But I would also like to introduce School-level variables.

```
dfSchool = data.frame(School = sort(unique(dt$school)),SchoolCat1.F = factor(c("S1","S2","S3","S2","S3","S1")),SchoolVar = (rnorm(6)))

> dfSchool
  School SchoolCat1.F   SchoolVar
1      I           S1 -0.08933959
2     II           S2  0.72704675
3    III           S3 -2.42612923
4     IV           S2 -0.78280022
5      V           S3 -0.23886568
6     VI           S1 -1.53925113
```

Using the data above as an example, and defining `y:= extro`, `x1:= open`, `x2:= agree`, `x:=social`, `j:= class level`, `k:= school level`, `x4:= SchoolCat1.F`, `x5:= SchoolVar`.

I want to write the following model:

[image]

how would it be represented?

I believe`m1 <- lmer(extro ~ open + agree + social + (1 | school/class), data = dt)` means that only the intercept is varying.

Therefore `m2 <- lmer(extro ~  (open|school/class) + (agree|school/class) + (social|school/class) + (1 | school/class), data = dt)` would be a good start.

However, I do not know how to include School-level variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model you propose has random slopes at the classroom and school levels for all student-level predictors. This may be a valid model for some data, but it would not be advisable for this particular data for reasons I outline below. That said, if you wanted to estimate the model that you showed, you would need to merge in the school-level variable (`SchoolVar`) that you created into the `dt` data frame:

```
library("lme4")
library("dplyr")
dt <-read.table("http://bayes.acs.unt.edu:8083/BayesContent/class/Jon/R_SC/Module9/lmm.data.txt",
                header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE) 
dt$classID <- paste(dt$school, dt$class, sep=".")
dfSchool = data.frame(school = sort(unique(dt$school)),SchoolCat1.F = factor(c("S1","S2","S3","S2","S3","S1")),SchoolVar = (rnorm(6)))
dtS <- merge(dt,dfSchool,by="school")
```

Then, you can estimate the maximal model with the `SchoolVar` predictor as follows:

```
m3 <- lmer(extro ~  1 + open + agree + social + SchoolVar + (1 + open + agree + social|classID) + 
               (1 + open + agree + social|school), data = dtS)
```

If this were a real analysis, you would not treat school as a random intercept given that there are only four schools in the data. Instead you would likely treat it as a fixed intercept, however doing so would not allow you to estimate the slope for `SchoolVar` because the latter is collinear with `as.factor(school)`:

```
m4 <- lmer(extro ~  1 + open + agree + social + as.factor(school) + (1 |classID), data = dtS)
```

Note that instead of `as.factor(school)`, you could use the `SchoolCat1.F` variable you created in the `dfSchool` data frame. But it makes little to no sense to include that variable in `m3`, above, because you already have random intercepts for schools. See the answer to [this recent question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/598383/include-single-variable-as-both-fixed-and-random-effect/598385#598385).

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense, I did not realize I could just merge to the data since it only varies when school changes. 

My data is different, just a bit hard to share, so I used this one instead. I am trying to predict laptime in a Formula 1 race, my first level is lap, second driver, and third circuit. 

So, I noticed you did not specify which level comes first with (1 | School/classID). Isn't it needed?

Comment: I think your data is crossed because I assume that drivers appear on multiple circuits. If so, then you want the separate specification `(1|driver) + (1|circuit)`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you.